# Doubt in the proof of Stokes theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

While proving the Stokes theorem in 2 dimension-

$$
\iint_R \left(\frac{\partial a_y}{\partial x }-\frac{\partial a_x}{\partial y}\right) dx\ dy = \oint_c(a_xdx +a_ydy)
$$

In this book(Mathematical Methods For Physics And Engineering
Textbook by K. F Riley), I came upon a step which seemed to be incorrect.
First it took an arbitrary closed curve in 2 dimension, and defined the range of x and y coordinates.
And started to solve the left side of the equation. The problem is this step-

$$
\int^{y_1}_{y_2} \left(\int_{x_1(y)}^{x_2(y)} \frac{\partial a_y}{\partial x }\ dx\right) dy=\int^{y_1}_{y_2}[a_y dy]_{x_1(y)}^{x_2(y)}
$$

How can it directly convert $\frac{\partial a_y}{\partial x }dx$ to $da_y$ ?

Comment: It's the fundamental theorem of calculus: what is $\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f'(t)\, dt$ if $f'$ is continuous?

Comment: @peek-a-boo, Note that here $a_y$ is function of both x and y

Comment: yes, but the same result holds true: if $f:\Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ is a (let's say $C^1$) function then $\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\bigg|_{(x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}, t, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n)} \, dt = f(x_1, \dots, \beta,\dots, x_n) - f(x_1, \dots, \alpha, \dots, x_n)$. The proof of this is immediate from the one-dimensional case. Just define $g(t) = f(x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}, t, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n)$, and apply the FTC like normal to $\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}g'(t)\, dt$. Everything works like normal because partial derivatives affect only one of the variables

Comment: Sir but gradient theorem tells that $da_y=\frac{\partial a_y}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial a_y}{\partial y} dy$

Comment: I never said that $da_y = \frac{\partial a_y}{\partial x}\, dx$ (I now realize that the equations you wrote in your answer are wrong.). I said if you integrate $\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\frac{\partial a_y}{\partial x}(x,y)\, dx$, then  you get $a_y(\beta,y) - a_y(\alpha,y)$, and this is because of the FTC.

Comment: Okay now I got it sir, But does this mean that $\int^{\beta}_{\alpha} \frac{da_y}{dx}(x,y)dx$ is not equal to $a_y(\beta,y) - a_y(\alpha,y)$, if they aren't equal then what should the integral be equal to? In b/w Thanks for the help

Comment: @peek-a-boo,here I am doing the full differentiation of $a_y$  wrt $x$ and then integrating

Comment: Writing $\frac{d a_y}{dx}(x,y)$ makes no sense; you have to use a partial derivative.

Comment: $\frac{d a_y}{dx}(x,y)=\frac{\partial a_y}{\partial x}  + \frac{\partial a_y}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: @peek-a-boo Isn't it sir?